# Why is the month and day of week always in English, even if the system language is Spanish?

Tags: localization

I tried restarting, changing settings, etc, but as you can see, it is still in English.

[image: Calender]

**Edit:**
I downloaded the source for indicator-datetime; from what I can see, the problem may be deeper. GTK?

Comment: Thanks for the translation; I was unaware that localization issues should also be in English, but that does make sense. I'll be sure to use that next time =)

Comment: Have you checked regional settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to language support. Selecting the "Regional Formats" tab. Selecting desired format/language (Spanish) and then click "Apply system-wide".

It took me ages work out how to change this between English and Portuguese, but it was that simple.

You need to reboot before changes take effect.

Comment: Indeed--you have to change the Regional settings as well; I did that, and all is well. Thank you!